# Convert string to ArrayList of String in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I have this string -

```
"["222.222.222.222", "21.21.21.21"]"; //Plain String which is actually an JSON Array
```

I want the output 222.222.222.222 and 21.21.21.21 in a ArrayList.

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: assist with what? what is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: 1) you can parse your string, ie by using regexp you could extract ip addresses from that string, 2) you could use one of libraries for parsing JSON string.

Comment: @user902383 regex for json parsing is a bad idea. 2) is a good idea

Comment: " Convert string to ArrayList of String in Java "

Comment: @weston for parsing entire json string, yes it will be bad idea, but not for  for extracting ip addresses from given string to put them into list. it all depends what you really want as end goal

Comment: @user902383 Yeah I agree it depends on the end goal. For example if you want to to fall over because someone formats the json slightly differently, then regex is the route to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using regular expressions. It will match any pattern with 4 integers separated by dots not just IPV4 addresses.

```
String text = "[\"222.222.222.222\", \"21.21.21.21\"]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

- [Arrays.asList documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)
- [String.split documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- [ArrayList(Collection) constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

Demo:

```
String s = "lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet";

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));

System.out.println(myList);  // prints [lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet]
```

Comment: no it doesnt work - it returns ["222.222.222.222"
 "21.21.21.21"]

Comment: ["222.222.222.222" - first iteration result
 "21.21.21.21"] - second iteration result

Comment: I only want IP address

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    str = str.substring(2);
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\", \"")));
```

where `str` is your string

Comment: do you know your code does not work? have a look here http://ideone.com/VXJXfi

Comment: please execute code now

Comment: have you executed your code and check result?

Comment: yes, i got this as output 222.222.222.222                                                                  
21.21.21.21

Comment: check again, as second entry you will have `21.21.21.21"` http://ideone.com/VXJXfi

Comment: its works fine for me... pls check

Comment: ups i broke it again:) http://ideone.com/VXJXfi